# Why is the CPU usage of my threaded python merge sort only 50% for each core?

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, sorting, cpu-usage

### Questions

Why is the CPU usage of my threaded python merge sort only 50% for each core?

Why does this result in "cannot create new thread" errors for relatively small inputs (100000)

How can I make this more pythonic? (It's very ugly.)

Linux/Ubuntu 12.4 64-bit i5 mobile (quad)

```
from random import shuffle
from threading import *

import time
import Queue


q = Queue.LifoQueue()

def merge_sort(num, q):
  end = len(num)

  if end > 1:
    mid = end / 2
    thread = Thread(target=merge_sort, args=(num[0:mid],q,))
    thread1 = Thread(target=merge_sort, args=(num[mid:end],q,))

    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread1.setDaemon(True)

    thread.start()
    thread1.start()

    thread.join()
    thread1.join()

    return merge(q.get(num), q.get(num))
  else:
    if end != 0:
     q.put(num)
    else:
     print "?????"
     return


def merge(num, num1):
  a = []
  while len(num) is not 0 and len(num1) is not 0:
    if num[0] < num1[0]:
      a.append(num.pop(0))
    else:
      a.append(num1.pop(0))
  if len(num) is not 0:
    for i in range(0,len(num)):
      a.append(num.pop(0))
  if len(num1) is not 0:
    for i in range(0,len(num1)):
      a.append(num1.pop(0))
  q.put(a)
  return a



def main():

    val = long(raw_input("Please enter the maximum value of the range:")) + 1
    start_time = time.time()
    numbers = xrange(0, val)
    shuffle(numbers)


    numbers = merge_sort(numbers[0:val], q)

#    print "Sorted list is: \n"
#    for number in numbers:
#      print number

    print str(time.time() - start_time) + " seconds to run.\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

For the 100000 input your code tries to create ~200000 threads. Python threads are real OS threads so the 50% CPU load that you are seeing is probably the system busy handling the threads. On my system the error happens around ~32000 threads.

Your code as written can't possibly work:

```py
from random import shuffle

#XXX won't work    
numbers = xrange(0, val)
shuffle(numbers)
```

`xrange()` is not a mutable sequence.

Note: the sorting takes much less time than the random shuffling of the array:

```py
import numpy as np

numbers = np.random.permutation(10000000) # here spent most of the time
numbers.sort()
```

If you want to sort parts of the array using different threads; you can do it:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads 

Pool(2).map(lambda a: a.sort(), [numbers[:N//2], numbers[N//2:]])
```

`a.sort()` releases GIL so the code uses 2 CPUs.

If you include the time it takes to merge the sorted parts; it may be faster just to sort the whole array at once (`numbers.sort()`) in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/), as by default [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) will be restricted to one core because of the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). This is why CPython cannot perform true CPU bound concurrent operations. But, CPython is still great at carrying out IO bound tasks.

There is a good article that describes the threading limitations of CPyton [here](http://www.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming).

Comment: I'll rephrase it @J.F.Sebastian.

Comment: I'd say it as: CPU-bound multithreaded pure Python code doesn't take advantage of multiple CPU cores (without using C extensions such as numpy that can release GIL or the `multiprocessing` module that uses multiple processes). Minor nitpick: [concurrent and parallel is not the same in programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) i.e., it is not necessary for concurrent operations to be executed in parallel (think about OSes that allowed multiple concurrent processes on a single CPU in the past).